# Using user input to perform calculations and store into an arrray

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, input

I am trying to use what a user inputs as a starting point for an array, it will then square it and add one and continue until 25 elements are stored. I know this can be done with the for loop, I am just not sure how to have the array start with user input.

```
import java.util.*;

public class arrayList {

    static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void printArrayDouble(double[] list, int numOfElements) {
        for ( int index = 0; index < numOfElements; index++)
            System.out.print(list[index] + " ");
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {


        double sqNum;
        double num;
        double [] sqNums = new double[25];
        double index = 0;   

        System.out.println("Please enter any integer!!");

        num = console.nextInt();
        sqNum = num;
        index = num;


        for(double i = 0; i < sqNums.length; i++) { 
            sqNums[(int) i] = Math.pow(i, 2);
        }

        arrayList.printArrayDouble(sqNums, sqNums.length);

    }

    }
```

I am trying to use the user input so the first number of the list, say 2, will  be squared then the next number of the list will be 3 then 4 then 5 and so on to the 25th element, with each of them being squared. If the input is n then the next element will be n + 1 and then become n and so on.

Comment: Why bother using double type counter in for loop? Use int. :)

Comment: Presumably so he can convert it to an INT on the fly...

Comment: You have never used the user input anywhere?

Comment: Can you show sample input and output?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, for input 2, you want output as

```
4 9 25 .... 25th element
```

if yes then the following code will do it

```
import java.util.*;

public class arrayList {

    static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void printArrayDouble(double[] list) {
        for ( int index = 0; index < list.length; index++)
            System.out.print(list[index] + " ");
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {


        double[] sqNums = new double[25];

        System.out.println("Please enter any integer!!");

        num = console.nextInt();


        for(int i = 0; i < 25; i++) { 
            sqNums[i] = Math.pow(i+num, 2);
        }

        arrayList.printArrayDouble(sqNums);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class arrayList
{

    static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void printArrayDouble(double[] list, int numOfElements)
    {
        for (int index = 0; index < numOfElements; index++)
            System.out.print(list[index] + " ");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        double sqNum;
        double num;
        double[] sqNums = new double[25];
        double index = 0;

        System.out.println("Please enter any integer!!");

        num = console.nextInt();
        sqNum = num;
        index = num;

        for (double i = 0; i < sqNums.length; i++)
        {
            sqNums[(int) i] = Math.pow(num, 2);
            num++;
        }

        arrayList.printArrayDouble(sqNums, sqNums.length);

    }

}
```